# Is there such a thing as a font viewer

Tags: fonts, tools

How do you know what glyphs are in a font?  Is there a tool that shows them?

Comment: Fontforge comes to mind. But i fear that this has nothing to do with TeX and friends and is off-topic.

Comment: I recommend [Fontmatrix](http://fontmatrix.be/). But as Johannes_B said, this is off-topic.

Comment: On a Windows system, [Nexus Font](http://www.xiles.net/nexusfont/) is a good choice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Can you please clarify your question.  Which type of fonts are you working with.  For some fonts the `fonttable` package will give you a list of glyphs.

Comment: Please give the OP a chance of improving his question before closing!

Comment: Is it not possible to wait for an OP feedback before closing? Maybe he will agree about the fact that the question has already an answer, but maybe he can provide additional details which make this a slightly different question. Don't worry: the closing bonus will still count 1, now, tomorrow or in few weeks..

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Maybe you should open a discussion on the Meta site for this. The OP's question is pretty clear. He wants to know how he can find out what glyphs a font has. Under the assumption he means a LaTeX font, then this question has been asked before, and already has an answer. I don't think duplicate questions should stay open (or be reopened) so that the OP can change the question to something else so that it isn't a duplicate anymore. Further discussion should go to the Meta site.

Comment: @Sverre: That has already been discussed thousands of times. My point is not _whether_ the question should be closed, but _when_. BTW: in general, if an OP makes clearer a question previously closed as duplicate and that question becomes a legitimate one, it totally deserves an answer. We are here to ask and answer, not to ask and close.

Answer (score 11):

From a terminal window, issue

```
pdftex fontchart
```

You'll be asked a TFM name, such as `cmr10`. The picture shows a fragment of what you get from `ecrm1000`:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding this answer to the dup'd question? :)